# Chart js cut the title and the legends

Tags: charts, chart.js, chart.js2, chart.js3

I wrote a chart.js graphic code setting the title and axis X and Y legends.  When I changed the version, the both dissapear in the graphic. Does anyone have the same problem?

I'm using chat.js min.js version 3.3.2 actually.

The options' code:

```
                   options : {
                            responsive : true,
                            hoverMode : 'index',
                            stacked : false,
                            title : {
                                display : true,
                                text : 'Título do Gráfico'
                            },
                            scales : {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    display: true,
                                    scaleLabel: {
                                        display: true,
                                        labelString: 'Unidade do Gráfico'
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options object is wrong, chart.js version 3 has some major breaking changes please read the migration guide for all of them: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html

For the title and legend they have been moved to the plugins section and the scales are no arrays anymore but just objects

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'title'
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          font: {
            size: 20
          }
        }
      },
      x: {
        ticks: {
          font: {
            size: 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```